# MySql composite index

Tags: mysql, sql

We are using MySql as our DB

The following query is runs on mysql table(approx 25million records). I pasted two queries here.The queries runs too slowly and I was wondering if better composite indexes might improve the situation.

Any idea on what the best composite index would be?

and Suggest me Is composite index required for these queries

FIRST QUERY

```
    EXPLAIN SELECT log_type,
       count(DISTINCT subscriber_id) AS distinct_count,
       count(*) as total_count
FROM stats.campaign_logs
WHERE domain = 'xxx'
  AND campaign_id='12345'
  AND log_type IN ('EMAIL_SENT', 'EMAIL_CLICKED', 'EMAIL_OPENED', 'UNSUBSCRIBED')
  AND log_time BETWEEN CONVERT_TZ('2015-02-12 00:00:00','+05:30','+00:00')
                   AND CONVERT_TZ('2015-02-19 23:59:58','+05:30','+00:00')
GROUP BY log_type
```

EXPLAIN of above query

```
+----+-------------+---------------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------+------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type        | possible_keys                                                | key                            | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                                                                        |
+----+-------------+---------------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------+------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | campaign_logs | index_merge | campaign_id_index,domain_index,log_type_index,log_time_index | campaign_id_index,domain_index | 153,153 | NULL | 35683 | Using intersect(campaign_id_index,domain_index); Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+---------------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------+------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

SECOND QUERY

```
SELECT campaign_id
     , subscriber_id
     , campaign_name
     , log_time
     , log_type
     , message
     , UNIX_TIMESTAMP(log_time) AS time 
  FROM campaign_logs 
 WHERE domain = 'xxx'  
   AND log_type = 'EMAIL_OPENED'  
 ORDER  
    BY log_time DESC 
 LIMIT 20;
```

EXPLAIN  of above query

```
+----+-------------+---------------+-------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type        | possible_keys               | key                         | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                                                                     |
+----+-------------+---------------+-------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | campaign_logs | index_merge | domain_index,log_type_index | domain_index,log_type_index | 153,153 | NULL | 118392 | Using intersect(domain_index,log_type_index); Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+---------------+-------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**THIRD QUERY**

```
EXPLAIN SELECT *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(log_time) AS time FROM stats.campaign_logs WHERE domain = 'xxx' AND log_type <> 'EMAIL_SLEEP' AND  subscriber_id = '123' ORDER BY log_time DESC LIMIT 100
```

EXPLAIN of above query

```
+----+-------------+---------------+------+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+-------+------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type | possible_keys                                   | key                 | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+---------------+------+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+-------+------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | campaign_logs | ref  | subscriber_id_index,domain_index,log_type_index | subscriber_id_index | 153     | const |   35 | Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+---------------+------+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+-------+------+-----------------------------+
```

If you want any other details I can provide here

**UPDATE (2016/April/22)** : 
Now we want to add one more column into existing table that is node id. One campaign can have multiple nodes. Whatever reports we are generating on campaigns we need those reports on individual nodes also now.

for example

```
SELECT log_type,
           count(DISTINCT subscriber_id) AS distinct_count,
           count(*) as total_count
    FROM stats.campaign_logs
    WHERE domain = 'xxx',
      AND campaign_id='12345',
      AND node_id = '34567',
      AND log_type IN ('EMAIL_SENT', 'EMAIL_CLICKED', 'EMAIL_OPENED', 'UNSUBSCRIBED')
      AND log_time BETWEEN CONVERT_TZ('2015-02-12 00:00:00','+05:30','+00:00')
                       AND CONVERT_TZ('2015-02-19 23:59:58','+05:30','+00:00')
    GROUP BY log_type

CREATE TABLE `camp_logs` (
  `domain` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `campaign_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subscriber_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `message` varchar(21000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `log_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `log_type` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `level` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `campaign_name` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `subscriber_id_index` (`subscriber_id`),
  KEY `log_type_index` (`log_type`),
  KEY `log_time_index` (`log_time`),
  KEY `campid_domain_logtype_logtime_subid_index` (`campaign_id`,`domain`,`log_type`,`log_time`,`subscriber_id`),
  KEY `domain_logtype_logtime_index` (`domain`,`log_type`,`log_time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

**SIZE issue**.

As we have two composite indexes , index file incresing rapidly. following are the table current stats.
Data size : 30 GB
Index size: 35 GB

for reports on node_id we want to update our existing composite index

**from**

```
KEY `campid_domain_logtype_logtime_subid_index` (`campaign_id`,`domain`,`log_type`,`log_time`,`subscriber_id`),
```

**to**

```
KEY `campid_domain_logtype_logtime_subid_nodeid_index` (`campaign_id`,`domain`,`log_type`,`log_time`,`subscriber_id`,`node_id`)
```

Could you suggest suitable composite indexes for both campaign and node level reports.

Thanks

Comment: What's the functional difference between `DATE('2015-02-12 00:00:00') AND DATE('2015-02-19 23:59:58')` and `'2015-02-12 00:00:00' AND '2015-02-19 23:59:58'`?

Comment: Try to simplify your queries. The first one have `GROUP BY` on both the inner query and the outer query. No index can help you on that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your first query:

```
SELECT A.log_type, count(*) as distinct_count, sum(A.total_count) as total_count
from (SELECT log_type, count(subscriber_id) as total_count
      FROM stats.campaign_logs
      WHERE domain = 'xxx' AND campaign_id = '12345' AND
            log_type IN ('EMAIL_SENT', 'EMAIL_CLICKED', 'EMAIL_OPENED', 'UNSUBSCRIBED') AND
             DATE(CONVERT_TZ(log_time,'+00:00','+05:30')) BETWEEN DATE('2015-02-12 00:00:00') AND DATE('2015-02-19 23:59:58')
      GROUP BY subscriber_id,log_type) A
GROUP BY A.log_type;
```

It is better written as:

```
      SELECT log_type, count(DISTINCT subscriber_id) as total_count
      FROM stats.campaign_logs
      WHERE domain = 'xxx' AND campaign_id = '12345' AND
            log_type IN ('EMAIL_SENT', 'EMAIL_CLICKED', 'EMAIL_OPENED', 'UNSUBSCRIBED') AND
             DATE(CONVERT_TZ(log_time, '+00:00', '+05:30')) BETWEEN DATE('2015-02-12 00:00:00') AND DATE('2015-02-19 23:59:58')
      GROUP BY log_type;
```

The best index on this is probably: `campaign_logs(domain, campaign_id, log_type, log_time, subscriber_id)`.  This is a covering index for the query.  The first three keys should be used for the `where` filtering.

Comment: Your rewrite lost distinct_count, which _might_ be `COUNT(DISTINCT subscriber_id, log_type)`.  The covering index looks good.

Comment: @RickJames . . . The original query is counting the number of distinct subscribers for each log type.  This is how the nested `group by` works in this case.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Thanks for your comment,I updated my first query and pasted one more query, total 3 queries , could you suggest best combinations of composite indexes for all queries

Answer (score 1):

For query 1, @Gordon Linoff's index is excellent (at least after the rewritten SELECT):

```
INDEX(domain, campaign_id, log_type, log_time, subscriber_id)
INDEX(campaign_id, domain, log_type, log_time, subscriber_id) -- equally good.
```

For query 2:  "index_merge" is a sign that you could probably benefit from a "compound index".  The second query is best handled by either of the following, which (I think) will compute the resultset with only 20 reads, not 118K, as estimated by EXPLAIN.

```
INDEX(domain, log_type, log_time)
INDEX(log_type, domain, log_time)
```

Keep in mind that, when you add indexes, you should get rid of redundant ones.  For example `INDEX(domain, ...)` makes `KEY domain_index (domain)` redundant, so the latter can be DROPped.

Overall, I would recommend

```
DROP INDEX(campaign_id_index),
ADD INDEX(campaign_id, domain, log_type, log_time, subscriber_id),
DROP INDEX(domain),
ADD INDEX(domain, log_type, log_time)
PRIMARY KEY(id, log_time) -- if you also add PARTITIONing; see below
```

Other recommendations:

- InnoDB Must have a PRIMARY KEY.  (A 6-byte hidden one was provided for you.)  Recommend `ADD COLUMN id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY`.
- Consider changing log_type from a bulky VARCHAR to an ENUM.
- If subscriber_id is really a number, then consider INT UNSIGNED.
- Will you eventually need to purge 'old' records?  PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(log_time)) is probably the best way.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint .  (And note that the PK would need to be (id, log_time).)
- "Partition pruning" cannot happen because log_time is buried in a pair of functions.  Use @axiac's rephrasing.
- innodb_buffer_pool_size should be set to about 70% of available RAM.

Comment: IF he was running just 1 query those DROP index would make sense.Question is who runs just a query or 2?

Comment: @Mihai , The point is that `INDEX(domain, <other cols>)` can handle all `WHERE` clauses that would benefit from `INDEX(domain)`.  So, there is virtually no reason to have both indexes.

Comment: @Rick Thanks for your comment,I updated my first query and pasted one more query, total 3 queries , could you suggest best combinations of composite indexes for all queries

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the first query as below:

```
SELECT log_type,
       count(DISTINCT subscriber_id) AS distinct_count,
       count(*) as total_count
FROM stats.campaign_logs
WHERE domain = 'xxx'
  AND campaign_id='12345'
  AND log_type IN ('EMAIL_SENT', 'EMAIL_CLICKED', 'EMAIL_OPENED', 'UNSUBSCRIBED')
  AND DATE(CONVERT_TZ(log_time,'+00:00','+05:30'))
      BETWEEN DATE('2015-02-12 00:00:00') AND DATE('2015-02-19 23:59:58')
GROUP BY log_type
```

It should produce the same results but it has no inner queries and a single `GROUP BY`.

The table already have all the indexes it needs.

The last condition (`DATE(...)`) cannot use any index because it have to compute a value using `log_time` for each row. Rewrite it to compare the bare value of `log_time` against some calculated values (apply `CONVERT_TZ()` to the interval bounds performing the reverse conversion).

This way it compares an indexed column `log_time` against some constant values, using the full power of indexing:

```
  AND log_time BETWEEN CONVERT_TZ('2015-02-12 00:00:00','+05:30','+00:00')
                   AND CONVERT_TZ('2015-02-19 23:59:58','+05:30','+00:00')
```

A multi-column index on columns `domain` and `log_type` (in this order) could help speeding both queries (they both have `Using intersect(domain_index,log_type_index)` in the `Extra` column returned by `EXPLAIN`).

If you create such an index then remove the index `domain_index`. An index on columns `domain` and `log_type` (in this order) can also be used as an index on `domain` only. MySQL can use it instead of `domain_index`. Having two identical indexes make the write operations slower and has no benefit.

Comment: Thanks for your comment,I updated my first query and pasted one more query, total 3 queries , could you suggest best combinations of composite indexes for all queries. Among above 3rd query is quick.

Answer (score 0):

For the *3* queries, I see very little sharing of indexes.  Instead, I would vote for these indexes (assuming you add `id ... AUTO_INCREMENT`)

```
PRIMARY KEY(id)
INDEX(campaign_id, domain, log_time)
INDEX(subscriber_id, domain)
INDEX(domain, log_type, log_time)
INDEX(log_time)
```

You should still consider the rest of the suggestions (ENUM, INT, etc).  These will shrink the disk footprint of both the data and the indexes.  Smaller -> more cacheable -> less I/O -> faster.

The `INDEX(log_time)` won't necessarily be used in any of the queries, but I kept it in, just in case the optimizer decides to target the `ORDER BY` instead of the `WHERE`.  I don't have enough information to predict; furthermore, I suspect the optimizer may pick one index one time, another index another time.

The 3 "compound" indexes could actually have the first two columns in either order.  I chose to mix things up so that the first column was different across them, thereby potentially helping whatever Query #4 is.

This answer is more "art" than "science"; I think it is about as good as it will get.